# Access timeline of swf in library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, timeline

On Google I got different opinions on this: Is it possible to access the timeline of an sfw (to use goto) in my library or do I really have to load it on runtime? If yes, how can I do it? Im using flash cs5 and ActionScript3.

Comment: please elaborate on what you mean by "access the timeline of an swf".  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to import an swf into the library and animate its content with goto("label"). I know, I could use a loader, but for some reasons, I would prefer, if it worked this way.

Comment: Yes you can goto any frame in any movieclip regardless if you add it to the library or load it using a Loader. The reason we use a Loader is so that we can change them without needing to recompile the main root swf!

Comment: Are you speaking about an access to the 'root' timeline, right? Objects can **NOT** access root timeline untill they are added to it.